# Encouraging C++ function pointer table inlining using copy ellision

Tags: c++, function, copy, function-pointers

In compiling some isolated tests to compare the ability of compilers to do devirtualization of simple single inheritance cases, versus CRTP, and versus inlining of 'C style' table of function pointers I noticed I appear to be getting more promising results from the latter (Testing using MSVC2010/2013 & XCode5/Clang).

So given 'modern' compilers ability to remove redundant copy by values and infer optimisation by value, it appears that even if you have large 'C style' tables of function pointers in a struct it might be better to prefer passing them by value as a general rule these days.  Note I am very much talking about this mostly from an approach that favours POD structs and pure static functions with no inheritance.

Does this seem like decent advice today if so?

Comment: This question really isn't very clear to me..

Comment: Basically is copying struct's full of function pointers by value around as a default a good idea these days as opposed to passing them by reference - as it appears to encourage better optimisation.

Comment: You won't know which way is faster until you measure both.

Comment: Which is faster isn't the total crux of this - although from my isolated tests so far mentioned in the question I state the latter is faster.  It would be interesting to argue that as eliminating redundant value copies is a lower hanging fruit then devirtualisation does that potentially mean that C style function tables should be preferred by design today - perhaps to benefit situations of static polymorphism?

Comment: Note that virtual functions can be inlined when using whole program optimization.